# How to give custom name via user to clicked images while saving into the gallery?

Tags: java, android

```
File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
           System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;

        try {
           // destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: you should add some more information about what you try to do, and what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are trying to give name randomly by using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

But if you want that user will decide the name then you have to take the name of an image as an input from the user.

```
public void saveImage(String imageName)
File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
           imageName + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;

        try {
           // destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```